# Limit sorted conditional xsl:for-each results to n values

Tags: xslt

I looked around on the site but wasn't able to locate a solution to a particular XSL problem. If you recognize this as a duplicate post I apologize and would be thankful to be pointed in the right direction.

Based on the relatively simple XML data set below I want to create a table by project but also limit the entries to something more 'digestible' like the 'newest' 10 for that project.

```
+---------------------------------------------------+  
| Alpha                   | Beta                    |  
+---------------------------------------------------+  
| Log_20091014_0900PM.xml | Log_20091015_0900PM.xml |  
| Log_20091013_0900PM.xml | ...                     |  
| ...                     |                         |  
+---------------------------------------------------+  
| Gamma                   | Delta                   |  
+---------------------------------------------------+  
| ...                     | ...                     |  
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

XML source data of the form:

```
<LogResults>
  <Result>
    <Project>Alpha</Project>
    <Data>Log_20091013_0900PM.xml</Data>
    <Name>Log_20091013_0900PM.xml</Name>
  </Result>
  <Result>
    <Project>Alpha</Project>
    <Data>Log_20091014_0900PM.xml</Data>
    <Name>Log_20091014_0900PM.xml</Name>
  </Result>
  <Result>
    <Project>Beta</Project>
    <Data>Log_20091015_0900PM.xml</Data>
    <Name>Log_20091015_0900PM.xml</Name>
  </Result>
  <Result>
    <Project>Gamma</Project>
    <Data>Log_20091016_0900PM.xml</Data>
    <Name>Log_20091016_0900PM.xml</Name>
  </Result>
  <Result>
    <Project>Delta</Project>
    <Data>Log_20091019_0900PM.xml</Data>
    <Name>Log_20091019_0900PM.xml</Name>
  </Result>
  <Result>
    <Project>Delta</Project>
    <Data>Log_20091020_0900PM.xml</Data>
    <Name>Log_20091020_0900PM.xml</Name>
  </Result>
  ...
</LogResults>
```

I am able to show *ALL* results for each project with appropriate variations of the following XSL:

```
<xsl:for-each select="LogResults/Result">
  <xsl:sort select="Data" order="descending" />
  <xsl:if test="(Project='Alpha')">
    <li>
      <a style="font-size:11pt;">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
          Alpha/<xsl:value-of select="Data" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**Question:**

Is it possible to limit the results to the 'newest' 10 (or 20 ...)? And if so how would you suggest this to be done?

I tried to use `position()` in the following way for example

```
<xsl:for-each select="(LogResults/Result) [position &lt; 11]">
```

or

```
<xsl:if test="(Project='Alpha')">
  <xsl:for-each select=". [position &lt; 11]">
    <li>
      <a style="font-size:11pt;">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
          Alpha/<xsl:value-of select="Data" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

But so far I couldn't get it to work. Certainly because it's more trail and error right now.

Thanks a lot for even reading this and any potential advice.
-T

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a detailed solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are quite close to the correct solution.

**Use**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="LogResults/Result[Project='Alpha']">
  <xsl:sort select="Data" order="descending" />
  <xsl:if test="not(position() > 10)">
    <li>
      <a style="font-size:11pt;">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
          Alpha/<xsl:value-of select="Data" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```